# "operation is still pending" external harddrive

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, automount

I have a 1TB Toshiba USB hard drive that is neither auto-mounting nor mounting through Files. I tried mounting the disk from the terminal, but I see this message:

```
Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error 
Failed to close volume /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and have very important stuff on the hard drive. I don't know much about terminal, so please explain as you would to a beginner.

sudo blkid gives

> /dev/sdc1: LABEL="TOSHIBA EXT" UUID="2AF8257EF8254981" TYPE="ntfs"
> PARTUUID="3d8ac32c-01"

Comment: Do you use this hard drive with other operating systems? For example, is it used with both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: yes i used to use it with windows but then i changed my os but even after changing my os i tried and it worked it has been some time and now it doesn't work

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1`? If the file system is damaged and the partition type is NTFS, then you will need to fix it with Windows. If the partition type is something else, then you may be able to check it within Linux.

Comment: Okay, then. `TYPE="ntfs"` is pretty clear. You will need to boot into Windows (if you still have it) and fix the hard drive there. This is the safest way to ensure that your important files are recoverable.

Comment: i dont have windows is there any safe way to recover it within linux itself?

Comment: NTFS is a *native* windows file-system, so if safety matters the check & fix should be done within windows.   Ubuntu has a `ntfsfix` tool (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) but to be safe it's best performing the fix where the *fs* is *native*

Comment: so if i just plug it in windows will it work.also after that i have to transport many files from my old pc (linux) to a new windows one which is on the way.so after i plug it in windows and recover it can i use it in linux?

Comment: *If* it can be recovered with Windows and later you want to use it with Ubuntu only then format it as EXT4.